# Sunrise - from earth - sun position or when sun rays reaches earth?

Tags: the-sun, sun-rays, sunrise

Time for the sun rays to reach earth is approximately 8 mins.

If time of the sun rise is 7:30 - which time is this? Time when sun rays reaches earth or time when earth and sun comes into correct position where sun is visible again after night?

If it is time when sun rays reaching earth - that means sun is already 8 mins away from that first position.

If it is second option - it means it's still 8 mins to wait until we actually see 'sun rising' - sun rays reaching earth.

So which time sun rise really is?

Comment: It's when we see the Sun's rays and includes refraction. It also is the moment we see the first glimpse of the sun.

Comment: That means it's not the actual position of the Sun, but when we see Sun's rays. Thanks. Can you please post your comment as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's when we see the Sun's rays and includes refraction. It also is the moment we see the first glimpse of the sun. Think of it this way: we humans need to know sunrise and sunset for our human activities; the fact that the sun is about eight light-minutes away doesn't concern us, doesn't affect the things we do. BTW, this is also true of solstices and equinoxes.

Comment: "BTW, this is also true of solstices and equinoxes." that's really interesting! Who knew?